# Karate API framework - How to assert the empty value of a key and if that value is empty then assert that some other key should not present

Tags: json, karate, jsonpath

Is there any way in Karate through which I can check that if any value is coming as empty string then some other key in the response should not present -

For example if you see below sample json response one of the `results[*].source.Descriptions[*].text` is empty and at the same node the preview `results[*].source.preview` is not present

So any straight forward solution in karate which can check that if Descriptions.text is `''` then preview should not be present at that node

```
 {
    "total": 10,
    "count": 10,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "source": {
                "type": "general",
                "Description": [
                    {
                        "text": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "source": {
                "type": "general",
                "preview": "Your name",
                "Description": [
                    {
                        "text": "Your name is Karate"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Read the docs in case anything is not clear:

```
* def isValid = function(x){ var desc = x.source.Description[0].text; return desc === '' ? !x.preview : true }
* match each response.results == '#? isValid(_)'
```

Comment: Hi @Peter Thomas

Thanks for your response !

Your solution would work if the Description.text is blank for the first node. I see that you have hardcoded the [0]th node. But what if there will be more nodes in the response where this field is blank. Does karate support any such matching such that I put x[*].source.description.text and it will work for all the nodes ?

Waiting for your response !

Thanks again !

Comment: Sure, I will accept them surely...also it's so good that you are always responsive so stay like that. Sometimes its hard to find everything on the doc so sharing the direct links (just like you had done above) is always helpful

Thanks again !